# Condition for an integral to be zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

For a bounded function $\operatorname{F}: \mathbb{R}_{\,\ge\ 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ ( *not necessarily non-negative* ), is it true that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}\,s}{(s^{2} + x^{2})^{\left(k + 3\right)/2}\,\,}\, \operatorname{F}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x = 0\quad
\forall s > 0  \iff \operatorname{F} \equiv 0
$$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is a positive constant $?$ Of course, one implication ($\leftarrow$) is true. What about the other one $?$.

Comment: Do you mean $F:\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ above?

Comment: @anomaly No, F does not need to be positive $F: \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb R$ and is just bounded.

Comment: Does $F$ need to be continuous? I'm pretty sure I could construct some sort of pathological function that would break this idea, but it wouldn't be continuous. **EDIT:** In response to your question edit, if we require $F\geq 0$ the statement is very easy to prove.

Comment: @K.defaoite No $F$ does not need to be continuous (although I would also be interested in seeing a positive result assuming continuity)

Comment: The converse is always false. Think about it like this: if I tell you that some weighted average of $F$ is zero, can you say that $F$ is always equal to zero?

Comment: @ThomasBakx You're right. I've now changed the statement of the problem a bit.

Comment: Still, without requiring continuity the converse statement is trivially false.

Comment: @metamorphy Yes, $F$ is measurable. Indeed, we can ask $F \in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Why is the density formulation equivalent to the $F = 0$ a.e.?

Answer (score 2):

Write

$$f_s(x) = \frac{x^ks}{(s^2+x^2)^{(k+3)/2}}$$

Notice that any such function vanishes at infinity.  Let $A$ be the subalgebra of $\textbf{C}_0((0, \infty), \mathbb{R})$ generated by the family $f_s$.  All these functions are positive on $(0, \infty)$ so the family doesn't vanish at any point, and it clearly separates points.

Thus by the locally compact version of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, $A$ is dense in $\textbf{C}_0((0, \infty), \mathbb{R})$, and $F$ satisfies your integral equation with $f_s$ replaced by any element of $A$.  Thus as a functional, using the Riesz Representation Theorem (using the uniqueness part) you get that $F \equiv 0$ a.e.

Comment: If you don't have the "locally compact version of Stone-Weierstrass" then just do your approximation on successively larger intervals $[\frac{1}{n}, n]$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add some details about why the assumptions of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem are satisfied. In particular, why does the family $f_s$ generate a subalgebra of $C_0((0,\infty),\mathbb R)$? Why does it separate the points?

Comment: You take the sub-algebra generated by the $f_n$, i.e. all finite linear combinations over $\mathbb{R}$.  It's an algebra by definition.  It separates any positive real (the case at $r = 0$ doesn't matter because a point is a null-set) because for any $r > 0$ you can find different $f_s$ that take different values on $r$.  I mean, just write out the equation.  If you're feeling very lazy, you can just add in functions $g_s = (1/2)f_s$ and take the algebra generated by both the $f$'s and $g$'s.  Can you check the answer as correct?  That's what you do on MSE when you get a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! But you need not only linear combinations. To conclude, you need to show that also the product $f_s f_t$ satisfies the condition $\int_0^\infty f_s f_t F(x) dx = 0$. How can one do that?

Comment: The usual squared Holder trick.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you add some details about this in the answer?